# Possible to use predict_proba without normalizing to 1?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm using `xgboost multi-class classifier` to predict a collection of things likely to fail. I want to run that prediction, and report anything that the classifier identifies with `probability > 75%`. However if I use `xgb.predict_proba()`, the sum of the results in the array add up to 1. So, if there are a lot of things likely to fail, they will all have tiny percentages in the result array.

Looking at [the predict_proba code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/multiclass.py#L351), I can see where the array is getting normalized. However I can't figure out how to prevent this.

In the end, I think my code would look something like this (except with the pre-normalized probabilities):

```
probas = xgb.predict_proba(single_element_dataframe)

for class_name in xgb.classes_:
    class_index = np.where(xgb.classes_ == class_name)
    proba = probas[0][class_index]
    if proba > 0:
        print(f"{class_name}: {proba}")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are trying to using the classifier to classify multiple things that can fail at the same time it's probably better to use a separate model for each of the classes since the model assumes that only one class can be true at a time. Because of this the values are normalized to get the percentage for each class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're doing [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification): find the most likely among N classes. Each class $C$ probability indicates how likely class $C$ is for the instance *as opposed to any other class*. This is why the probabilities sum to 1: in this setting, there is only one "correct" class, so two classes cannot both have high probability.

Based on your description you should use [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification): find all the classes that apply to the instances among N classes. In this case each class $C$ probability indicates how likely this instance has class $C$ *as opposed to not having class $C$* (i.e. independently from any other class). Naturally the consequence is that the probabilities don't sum to one, since they are independent of each other.

Note: multi-label classification is exactly the same as training a binary model for every class independently.